# System Center Service Manager - Get-SCSMObject Filter

Tags: c#, powershell, system-center

I want to search for all UserComments of all Incidents in System Center Service Manager containing a bracket [.

So I tried it with Criteria:

```
$clUserComment = get-scsmclass System.WorkItem.TroubleTicket.UserCommentLog 
$criteria = New-Object "Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common.EnterpriseManagementObjectCriteria" `
                ("Comment like '%[%'", $clUserComment )
$comments = Get-SCSMObject -Criteria $criteria
```

and with filter:

```
$comments = Get-SCSMObject -Class $clUserComment -Filter "Comment -like '%[%'"
```

I guess, that '[' is a special char, but don't know how to escape that.

And yes, one answer is adding a where-Object

```
 $doitComments = $comments | Where-Object { $_.comment -match '\[' }
```

but this answer is too slow for my usecase.

(c# tag because maybe experience with criteria)
tia

Comment: You are looking for the word "Comment"  Try -Filter "'%[%'"

Comment: I'm looking for appearances from '[' in the property comment. Therefor it is not possible to remove the property from filter, because there will be an error.